# PHP Scope Issue Between Included File Variable, Global Function, And Classes

Tags: php, function, class, variables, scope

I'm having a problem figuring out why a function within a class isn't properly using the global function for connecting to a database. It can access the function fine and it will set up a connection string, but it connects to the wrong database and I think it has to do with scoping, but not sure how to remedy it.

It's set up something like this

```
include "variableScript.php"; //contains variable set by another script

//other code

function connectDB(){
   global $scriptVar;
   $db;

   if(strcmp($scriptVar, 'DB1') == 0){
      $db = 'DB1';
   }
   else{
      $db = 'DB2';
   }

   //DB connection code here, user/pass come elsewhere.
}

//other code

class A{ //this class is called elsewhere
   // class variables here, one being a database connector
   // class constructor

   public function run(){
      $this->dbConn = connectDB();
      //other code in run function
   }

   // other class function
}
```

Now, I know for sure that $scriptVar is set correctly and that the database selected is correct when it's another script's function (not in a class) using the connectDB function so I think it has to deal with the scoping and the class. As I said, I think it's a scoping issue. When the global function is called from inside the class, I don't think it knows what $scriptVar is. I'm not sure if it's trying to find $scriptVar in the class or elsewhere. When I tried putting global $scriptVar inside class A's function that calls the other, it didn't work out for me.

Anyone know what could be up?

Comment: I actually do know, but I don't have much choice over this where I work :\ I would like to rewrite a ton of the code, but I don't have the time/ability because of how much it will break. But hopefully in the near future I can, for now, I need to get something to work properly. Then I can talk to my boss about rewriting things and figure out all who work with the code so they can alter their code.

You should see how our database is set up here too, there are some... bad coding practices.

Answer (score 0):

```
function connectDB(){
   global $scriptVar;
   $db="";

   if(strcmp($scriptVar, 'DB1') == 0){
      $db = 'DB1';
   }
   else{
      $db = 'DB2';
   }

   //DB connection code here, user/pass come elsewhere.
}
```

i think it will be helpful to you if it will not work you can use this code

```
class R_DB
{   
    public $host     = "localhost";
    public $database = "dbname"; 
    public $username = "root"; 
    public $password = ""; 
    public $conId    = 0;  
    public $row;          

 //call connection method upon constructing 
 public function __construct(){
  $this->dbConnect(); 
 }

 //connection to the database
 public function dbConnect() 
    { 
        if( 0 == $this->conId ) 
            $this->conId=mysql_connect( $this->host, $this->username, $this->password ); 
        if( !$this->conId ) 
   $this->stopExec( "Trying to connect.... Result: failed" ); 
        if( !mysql_query( sprintf( "use %s", $this->database ), $this->conId ) ) 
            $this->stopExec( "cannot use database ".$this->database ); 
 } 
}
```

can use optional db here using

when

```
public function dbConnect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) 
    { 
        if( 0 == $this->conId ) 
            $this->conId=mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname ); 
        if( !$this->conId ) 
   $this->stopExec( "Trying to connect.... Result: failed" ); 
        if( !mysql_query( sprintf( "use %s", $dbname ), $this->conId ) ) 
            $this->stopExec( "cannot use database ".$this->database ); 
 }
```